# what's the difference of using forward salsh "/" and "public" name for addressing public folder in vite for react?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I was trying to access my files in public folder so once I used `/` for accessing those files in public, next time I used `public` name to access those, so when I use public name, a warning pops up in terminal mentioning that I should use `/` for accessing public folder, however there is no issue when I use `public` name for addressing, so I was wondering is there any difference between addressing public directory with `/` and `public` directory?

addressing with `public` name:

```
import logo from "public/test.svg"
```

addressing with forward slash:

```
 import logo from "/test.svg"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your config. But in most cases starting with *forward slash* `/` means absolute path. So you're starting from the root directory of your project, while starting with `public` is assumed to be starting from a relative path, where `public` is assumed to be accessible from your current directory

Comment: so basically it doesn't affect the performance?@normalcepalin

Comment: Yes, it doesn't affect the perfomance @scorpian111

Answer (score -1):

public: This method uses the "public" folder name in the file path of the project's files. For example, if you place a file named logo.png in the public folder, you can reference it like this: public/logo.png.

/: This method uses a / as the starting point for the public folder file paths. For example, if you place the logo.png file in the public folder, you can reference it like this: /logo.png.

Both methods generally yield the same result in Vite, but using public may provide clearer semantics and better code readability, while using / can make the code shorter. The choice between these two methods largely depends on personal preference and project standards.

Comment: chat gpt?@soheildev

Comment: no i use bing :::)

Comment: AI generated content is banned on StackOverflow - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831